# golang snap installation: cgo.a: read-only file system

Tags: ubuntu, go, goland

I have installed go 1.11 using the snap package as described here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Ubuntu

```
# This will give you the latest version of go
$ sudo snap install --classic go
```

Things in general work well, however, when I tried to compile a project that uses `cgo`, I get the following error:

```
/snap/go/2635/bin/go test -c -i -o /tmp/___Test_GetVersion_in_tests_go tests_go #gosetup
go test runtime/cgo: open /snap/go/2635/pkg/linux_amd64/runtime/cgo.a: read-only file system
```

What could be happening? Is this a known issue in the snap installation?

Comment: Can you remove the -i flag?  It looks like you're asking the test tool to install some build artifacts into a path to which you don't have access.   https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24674

Comment: mm.. I am actually using goland so that parameter is automatic. I will try to remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you came here looking for how to resolve this error for VSCode - it took me a little bit to find the setting.

`File -> Preferences -> Settings`

In the settings pane...
`User Settings -> Extensions -> Go configuration`

Scroll about 2/3rds of the way down until you get to `Install Dependencies When Building`. Uncheck that one and restart VSCode.

So far has been working for me (running Ubuntu 18)

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion provided by `stderr`, to remove the `-i` argument, resolves this.

In case you are using the GoLand IDE, you can remove the `-i` argument by going to `Run` -> `Edit Configurations...` -> `Go tool arguments`